# Upload a file on server [internal error 500]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3

On ruby on rails I have written a code where I can upload a file on the amazon console, when i run the code from the localhost i am able to upload the file successfully . But i try to upload it from the swagger i am getting a error called : `internal error 500`. I have checked the log file and found the following  error:

> /2013/12/23 09:34:05 [crit] 1705#0: *315335 open() "/tmp/passenger-standalone.1627/client_body_temp/0000000007" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 10.29.36.248, server: _, request: "POST /v1/models/GTAG2/modelfirmware.json?api_key=5rx2mR3muK1mCydYerw3 HTTP/1.1", host: "dev-api-3.elasticbeanstalk.com"

Can anyone tell me how to fix this bug? In my S3 the folder and bucket is available.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you may be encountering issues similar to one of the following:

1. [Phusion-Passenger Issue #654](http://code.google.com/p/phusion-passenger/issues/detail?id=654) where something (a daemon) is deleting (cleaning) /tmp files while they are still in use.
2. [Issue Uploading Files from Rails app hosted on Elastic Beanstalk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15714042/issue-uploading-files-from-rails-app-hosted-on-elastic-beanstalk)

I'd check to make sure nothing is running on your system that could be deleting/cleaning files under /tmp while Passenger is running.